# Unit test component with matSlideToggle in template

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, karma-jasmine

I have matSlideToggle binded to formControl value. I want to create unit test that tests when slide toggle value has been changed then the status value in the form is changed accordingly.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
...
      <mat-slide-toggle
        formControlName="status"
        (change)="changed($event)"
      >
        Status
      </mat-slide-toggle>
...
</form>
```

form is initialized as

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
...
      status: new FormControl(false),
...
    });
  }
```

changed method:

```
  changed(status) {
    console.log(
      'status',
      status,
      this.form.get('status').value
    );
  }
```

In my test I do the following:

```
const statusToggleEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MatSlideToggle));
statusToggleEl.triggerEventHandler('change', { checked: true });
fixture.detectChanges();
```

This code triggers changed method and in console I can see "status {checked: true} false", which is not supposed behaviour.